# Combining multiple CountIf statements into single countIfs statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following If conditions, I want to combine them into a single countIfs statement using And.

```
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range("A2:A" & iTotRecsC), Val2) > 0 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range("B2:B" & iTotRecsB), Val1) > 0 Then
         If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range("C2:C" & iTotRecsE), Val3) > 0 Then
```

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you wanting to compare if the values are all found on the same row, or just if the values are found in the ranges regardless of row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will this work?  I don't think you can combine those into a single CountIf.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range("A2:A" & iTotRecsC), Val2) > 0 _
And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range("B2:B" & iTotRecsB), Val1) > 0 _
And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(completed.Range("C2:C" & iTotRecsE), Val3) > 0 Then
```